# Member access expression applying to a variable of an incomplete type

Tags: c++, class

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    static const int b = 42;
    static const A *a;
    int ca[b]; //OK
    int c[a -> b]; //1, ill-formed
};

int main(){ }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad47fab753ad97ae)**

At `//1`, the class type is still being considered as an incomplete object type (relevant section `N4296::9.2/2 [class.mem]`). But we can't apply the class-member-access expression to it. Why?

Couldn't you explain why the program is ill-formed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the member access operators can only be applied to a complete type, as specified by C++11 5.2.5 [expr.ref]/2:

> For the first option (dot) the first expression shall have complete class type. For the second option (arrow) the first expression shall have pointer to complete class type.

If you're asking why that rule exists: because, unless the class is complete, so that the member has been declared, there's no way to tell how to interpret the member name.